# Boostrap button group, hide inactive buttons on print

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

Could anyone point me in the right direction here. I need to only show the active buttons when I print the page

```css
#myButtons label:not([.active]) {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<form id="test" method="post">

  <div id="myButtons" class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-primary active">
      <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" checked value="one"> Radio 1 (preselected)
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
      <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off" value="two"> Radio 2
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
      <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" autocomplete="off" value="three"> Radio 3
    </label
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You chould use some css rule like :

```
#myButtons label:not(.active) {
    display: none;
}
```

and then add the @media print rules to apply only while printing

```
@media print {
    #myButtons label:not(.active) {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

docs:

[not selector css3](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_not.asp)

Comment: sorry, i misread your html, answer has been corrected . Fiddle fork : https://jsfiddle.net/s7cw000k/

Comment: Thanks, I think it's the label it needs applying to. Updated my post to include your suggestion. Still not working i'm afraid

Answer (score 0):

right now i don't have my device,but the  below mentioned code will help you surly...

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){   
    if(($("label").hasClass("active"))){
       $('.btn-primary').hide();
       $('.active').show();
    }

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Use the below Code

```
 $("label").click(function () {
        $("label.active").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
```